# Moving stored values down one in [R]

Tags: r, assign

I'm a coding newbie. I want to move stored values down one. So my current code looks like this:

```
NEWxrp14 <- NEWxrp15
NEWxrp13 <- NEWxrp14
NEWxrp12 <- NEWxrp13
...
NEWxrp1 <- NEWxrp2
```

Of course when I run this, all the values from 1-15 become what was stored as number 15. Instead I want 15 to become 14, 14 to become 13, and so on, each time I run the script. The '1st' (aka `NEWxrp15`) value is created from a formula. Basically after 15 times of running the script, that value should be stored as `NEWxrp1`.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: for more explanation, I'm taking a stock price from the internet every minute, and want the last 15 minutes stored in R. Hence why every minute (when the script runs again) I want them all to move down one. Since the stock prices is stochastic I dont really know how I can give a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide some example data and more context

Comment: have you tried just reversing the order? ;o) meaning your last line becomes the first line and so on

Answer (score 1):

Try to use vectors of values instead of single variables for each value.

Since you did not specify the data type (scalar or more complex) I am assuming integers here:

```
NEWxrp <- 1:15   # create a vector of 15 increasing numbers
NEWxrp
#   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
NEWxrp[1:14] <- NEWxrp[2:15]
NEWxrp
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15
```

PS: Please always add a minimal reproducible example to your questions (incl. data so that the code can be run by everyone to find a solution).

PS2: For a more sophisticated version search for `shift` function

Comment: Also `head(x, -1) <- tail(x, -1)` looks like it will work.